# Visual Studio remove space before brackets

Tags: c#, visual-studio, format, development-environment

I tried to adjust the code formatting in Visual Studio 2017, but I have one problem:
Normally my code looks like this:

```
if(...){

}
```

but Visual Studio always converts the code to look something like this:

```
if(...) {

}
```

It adds the blank space before the opening bracket and I don't know how to remove it. I adjusted all settings to make the code look like it should, but I can't find an option for white space before brackets...

I'm thankful for any help.

Comment: The C# way is to new-line the opening bracket anyway.  Also, that space isnt going to effect your compiled code, why break the trend/norm?  The IDE is trying to help normalize your code so other people arent lost in a weird format

Comment: I coded that way for several years, but now I have to change my editor and I want to continue coding like that. That's just a habit.

Comment: I would suggest breaking that habit now, you wanna try to stick with the conventions of the language so that other developers can read and understand your code. The IDE handles all the new-line and everything for you so you are actually doing more work to change the default behavior

Comment: I (strongly) disagree with newlining the opening bracket, but I think the space is good, and would prefer one after `if` as well.

Comment: I think you would need to try ReSharper to fix this with VS 2017.